# Write data from input to Firebase database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-scope, firebase-realtime-database

I wanna send data from input towards Firebase database using **$scope**. I don't know how can I send from $scope all data towards firebase database.
Here is the html code :

```
  <div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <table id="table_curse" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table ">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
                <td>
                  <select><option value="Incarcare">Incarcare</option><option value="Descarcare">Descarcare</option></select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="choice.Locatie" name="Locatie" placeholder="Locatie" ></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="choice.Nr" name="Nr" placeholder="Nr" style="width: 40px;"></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="choice.Greutate" name="Greutate" placeholder="Greutate"></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="choice.Referinta" name="Referinta" placeholder="Referinta"></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="choice.Observatii" name="Observatii" placeholder="Observatii"></td>

                 <td><button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">Sterge pas</button></td>

             </tr>
          </div>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

This is the javascript for the dynamic table:

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.choices = [{id: 'pas1'}];

  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
    $scope.choices.push({'id':'pas'+newItemNo});
  };

  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
    $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
  };

});
</script>
```